# Get new location and radius from Circle component in React Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I'm using React Google Maps API package to create a map component with a circle component inside it. Here is the package from the npm registry https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api.

I'm using `Circle` component inside a `Google Map` component.
I set the `Circle` to be draggable and resizable.

I need to get the new value of `center` for every drag action and get the new value of `radius` for every resize action.
In this https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/#circle documentation, the `onCenterChanged` and `onRadiusChanged` have type of `void`.

So **my question is** how can I get the new value of `center` for every drag action and get the new value of `radius` for every resize action using this library?

Or is there any solution using the original google maps library?

Here is the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/circle-react-google-maps-api-lo9f6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading again the documentation and a lot of tries, I found the solution to get the new values of location and radius from the new position/size of the Circle.

I added `onLoad` prop and set the circle using it.
Then I printed the `circle` state value to check whether there were lat, lng, and radius values or not.

I found those values and here was the code.

```js
const [ circle, setCircle ] = useState(null)

<Circle
  center={mapCenter}
  radius={radius}
  options={circleOptions}
  onLoad={(circle) => setCircle(circle)}
  onUnmount={(circle) => setCircle(null)}
  onCenterChanged={() => circle && setCircleCenter({ lat: circle['center'].lat(), lng: circle['center'].lng() })}
  onRadiusChanged={() => circle && setRadius(parseInt(circle['radius']))}
/>
```